# Реализация фабричного метода с абстрактным классом

Tags: php, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Возникла следующая проблема. Реализовал паттерн Фабричный метод на основе обобщенного конструктора(с помощью статического метода getFigure в классе Figure).

```
abstract class Figure{

static function getFigure(string $type)
{
    switch ($type){
        case "Rectangle": return new Rectangle(); break;
        case "Circle": return new Circle(); break;
        default: echo "Неправильный параметр"; return null; break;
    }
}

abstract function draw();

}
class Rectangle extends Figure{
    function draw(){ echo "Rectangle"; }
 }
class Circle extends Figure{
    function draw(){ echo "Circle"; }
 }
```

Все работает, но есть один нюанс:

Сам статичный метод вызывается так:`Figure::getFigure('Circle')->draw();`
НО проблема в том, что это статичный метод так же наследуется и подклассами, и соотвественно я могу вызвать его так:`Circle::getFigure('Circle')->draw();` 
Так вот вопрос, как мне можно ограничить вызов статического метода в наследуемых классах?
Конечно можно просто переопределить в каждом классе так, Но ведь это очень неудобно прописывать это в каждом классе:

```
static function getFigure(string $type){}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете Статическую Фабрику. Текущая форма реализации не совсем верна. Фабрика должна лишь создать объект, но не содержать никакой логики данного объекта.

```
class FigureFactory
{
    static function build(string $type)
    {
        switch ($type){
            case "Rectangle": 
                return new Rectangle();
            case "Circle":
                return new Circle();
            default:
                echo "Неправильный параметр";
                return null;
        }
    }
}

interface Figure
{
    public function draw();
}

class Circle implements Figure
{
    function draw()
    {
        echo "Circle";
    }
}

FigureFactory::build('Circle')->draw(); // Circle
Circle::build('Circle')->draw(); // Uncaught Error
```